# How to Select Rows into Columns Dynamically Oracle

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, plsql

Hi i'm trying to select rows into columns, i have used **Listagg** function to retrieve comma separated column and then parse it in Java code, it works fine for small queries (about 150,000 rows) when i retrieve large queries it become a problem for memory and cpu.

Is there any way to select the rows as columns dynamically by query? for example:

**Original result**

[image]

**Listagg result**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

Thank you!